# Rotate bones using a texture?

Tags: bones

I have an armature, and I want to do a "flailing limbs" effect. I figure a good way to do this would be to have a noise texture and rotate the bones in accordance with the texture.

Is this something that can be done? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible, haven't found any mechanism to link texture value to bone transformation. But we can make random flailing movement by adding **Noise** modifier to the bone's rotation f-curve. From the manual entry [on F-Curve Modifiers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html#noise), this modifier

> Modifies the curve with a noise formula. This is useful for creating
> subtle or extreme randomness to animated movements, like camera shake.

If applied to the bone's rotation in at least one axis, it could create the effect you wanted:

[image: 1a]

Comment: Thanks. Turns out the effect I'm after is to just use a cyclic motion, but this will definitely be helpful.